# verify js pbkdf2-sha256 hash with python passlib

Tags: javascript, python, sha256, passlib

I encrypt a random string in python file and hashit in javascript using [pbkdf2-sha256](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pbkdf2-sha256) but some how the verification fails with python passlib . any idea why?

my python code is :

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
import os,random,string
t = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in 
range(7))
h = os.popen('node 
D:/mojtaba/repos/restaurant_app/frontend/node_modules/a.js '+t).read()[:-2]
a = pbkdf2_sha256.verify(t,h)
print(a)
```

and js file contains :

```
var pbkdf2 = require('pbkdf2-sha256');
var salt = 'WitFCKH03htDKAVA6L3Xmg';
var algorithm = "pbkdf2-sha256";
var iterations = 29000;
var hashed = pbkdf2(process.argv[2], new Buffer(salt), iterations, 
32).toString('base64');
var finalPass = '$'+algorithm +'$'+ iterations +'$'+  salt +'$'+  hashed;
console.log(finalPass)
```

and result is always false